# Reproducing CRAN GCC-UBSAN test results 'at home' on ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, cran

I'm scratching my head on this one. How to reproduce 
 the results of [CRAN's gcc ubsan tests of my package](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/bdr/memtests/gcc-UBSAN/FastRCS-Ex.Rout) at home, on ubuntu? (the instructions on the preparation steps come from [here](https://github.com/rocker-org/r-devel-san/blob/master/Dockerfile))

1) I install-update all needed packages:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install bash-completion bison debhelper default-jdk g++ gcc gfortran groff-base libblas-dev libbz2-dev libcairo2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev liblapack-dev liblzma-dev libncurses5-dev libpango1.0-dev libpcre3-dev libpng-dev libreadline-dev libtiff5-dev libx11-dev libxt-dev mpack subversion tcl8.5-dev texinfo texlive-base texlive-extra-utils texlive-fonts-extra texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-generic-recommended texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended tk8.5-dev valgrind x11proto-core-dev xauth xdg-utils xfonts-base xvfb zlib1g-dev
```

2) Built Rdevel with the needed options:

```
cd /tmp
svn co http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk R-devel 
cd /tmp/R-devel 
R_PAPERSIZE=letter R_BATCHSAVE="--no-save --no-restore" PAGER=/usr/bin/pager  PERL=/usr/bin/perl  R_UNZIPCMD=/usr/bin/unzip  R_ZIPCMD=/usr/bin/zip  R_PRINTCMD=/usr/bin/lpr  LIBnn=lib  AWK=/usr/bin/awk  CFLAGS="-pipe -std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic -O2"  CXXFLAGS="-pipe -Wall -pedantic -O2"  CC="gcc -fsanitize=address,undefined"  CXX="g++ -fsanitize=address,undefined"  CXX1X="g++ -fsanitize=address,undefined"  FC="gfortran -fsanitize=address,undefined"  F77="gfortran -fsanitize=address,undefined" ./configure --enable-R-shlib --without-blas --without-lapack --with-readline --without-recommended-packages --program-suffix=dev --disable-openmp 
make 
make install 
make clean
```

3) finally, build/compile said package locally with the as-cran flag:

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/FastRCS_0.0.6.tar.gz
tar -xvzf FastRCS_0.0.6.tar.gz
Rdevel CMD check --as-cran FastRCS
```

But I don't get the same bug report as on cran (see [here](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/bdr/memtests/gcc-UBSAN/FastRCS-Ex.Rout)). I mean for example this one:

```
/usr/local/gcc5/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/include/emmintrin.h:140:21: runtime error: load of misaligned address 0x61800007fc84 for type 'const double', which requires 8 byte alignment
0x61800007fc84: note: pointer points here
  00 00 80 3f 00 00 80 3f  00 00 80 3f 00 00 80 3f  00 00 80 3f 00 00 80 3f  00 00 80 3f 00 00 80 3f
```

What is wrong with the script I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another out-of-the-box solution seems to be using [r-hub package](https://github.com/r-hub/rhub) / [service](https://builder.r-hub.io/), that works in similar fashion as `devtools::check()`, you just need to run

```
rhub::check_with_sanitizers()
```

Comment: That's the easiest way

Comment: Which of course wasn't available when I wrote my answer... but at least the containers help Gabor build r-hub.

Answer (score 3):

It is doable, but quite some work.  And it is also a prime candidate for something that [docker](http://www.docker.com) is *very* good for.  So I created two different Docker containers:

- [SAN with clang](https://github.com/rocker-org/r-devel-san-clang)
- [SAN with gcc](https://github.com/rocker-org/r-devel-san)

The corresponding Docker images are on [the Docker hub](http://hub.docker.com) ready for your download.

I also wrote one [longer blog post about this for UBSAN](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2015/01/18/).

Comment: I'm not sure what I do wrong. Inputing the line `docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/mnt rocker/r-devel-ubsan-clang check.r --setwd /mnt --install-deps RcppAnnoy_0.0.5.tar.gz` from the blog post I get> `The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/downloaded_packages’
Warning: ‘RcppAnnoy_0.0.5.tar.gz’ is neither a file nor directory, skipping`

Comment: Maybe use `/bin/bash`  for a shell and run `RD CMD check ...` by hand.

Comment: (I mean I get  `* DONE (RcppAnnoy)

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/downloaded_packages’
Warning: ‘RcppAnnoy_0.0.5.tar.gz’ is neither a file nor directory, skipping`)

Comment: I am not sure why you decided to unaccept this answer.  It provides you with links to premade SAN/UBSAN images. My blog posts show worked examples. What more do you want?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel is this answer still applicable? It seems that the check.r file link is dead in your blog post. Could you point any up-to-date sources line your blog post?

Comment: The file is (of course) still there, the link was (apparently always) wrong: lacks an `inst/`.  Just go to the littler repo or install littler from CRAN.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, as always awesome work and much appreciated. It seems that `rhub` is having issues and your knowledge bombs have helped out tremendously.  I still haven't figure out my issue, but the light is drawing near.

Comment: Do talk to Gabor about rhub then -- it is a very similar (Docker-based) setup.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use R-hub Docker images locally, in particular [thanks to helper functions of the `rhub` package](https://r-hub.github.io/rhub/articles/local-debugging.html). These functions do not work on Windows yet, though.

Disclaimer: I am a contributor to the `rhub` package.